# Handle back key event on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, key, cocos2d-x, back, cocos2d-x-3.0

How to handle back key event in Cocos2dx 3.3 Windows Phone 8 C++?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`HardwareButtons.BackPressed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.ui.input.hardwarebuttons.backpressed.aspx) event to handle the back key press. Set the `Handled` property on the event args to `true` if you want to avoid the default behaviour of closing the app.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one                   -

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/solved-windows-phone-8-framework-back-button-handling/5732.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution with cocos2dx 3.3

In header file .h

```
virtual void onKeyReleased(cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, cocos2d::Event* event);
```

And cpp file

```
void MrGreen::onKeyReleased(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
if (keyCode == EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_ESCAPE)
{

}
}
```